# Reading the right dir but outputs it's wrong?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

the following code [below] is in a .js file based in "Reloaders" folder and I'm trying to reach the "Commands" folder.

Yet every attempt I do I get the error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../Commands'`

### Code

```js
const categories = fs.readdirSync("../Commands");
```

#### Tree Output

```yaml
C:.
+---lib
|   +---Collections
|   +---Commands
|   +---Events
|   +---Handlers
|   +---Reloaders
|   \---Settings
```

#### Full Code

```js
var fs = require("fs");
const chokidar = require("chokidar");
const { basename } = require("path");
const Logger = require("../Handlers/LogHandler");
const { commands, aliases } = require("../Collectors/DiscordCollectors")
const categories = fs.readdirSync("../Commands");

const CommandReloader = async () => {
    categories.forEach(category => {
        chokidar.watch(`../Commands/${category}`, {
            awaitWriteFinish: true
        }).on("change", (file) => {
            const commandName = basename(file, ".js")
            delete require.cache[require.resolve(process.cwd() + `/lib/Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`)];
            delete require.cache[require.resolve(process.cwd() + `/lib/Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`)];
            commands.delete(process.cwd() + `/lib/Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`);
            Logger.log("Command Reloader", `Deleted ${commandName} from ${category}.`);
            console.log(commands.get(commandName))

            const props = require(process.cwd() + `/lib/Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`);
            commands.set(commandName, props);
            props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                aliases.set(alias, commandName);
            });

            Logger.log("Command Reloader", `Reloaded ${commandName} from ${category}.`);
        });
    });
};

module.exports.start = CommandReloader;
```

#### Cache Issue

```js
const commandName = basename(file, ".js")
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`${__dirname}/../Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`)];
commands.delete(`${__dirname}/../Commands/${category}/${commandName}.js`);
console.log(commands.get(commandName))
Logger.log("Command Reloader", `Deleted ${commandName} from ${category}.`);
```

Output from cache issue:

```yaml
[24/10/2020 22:10:03] [ Command Loader ] | Loaded lol from General.
[24/10/2020 22:10:06] [ Command Reloader ] | Deleted lol2 from Admin.
{
  run: [Function],
  help: {
    name: 'lol',
    aliases: [ 'l', 'o', 'l' ],
    description: 'Lol',
    usage: '(command name) ',
    category: 'Admin'
  }
}
[24/10/2020 22:10:06] [ Command Reloader ] | Reloaded lol2 from Admin.
```

Comment: The path needs to be relative to the working dir, not the .js file.

Comment: You can make it relative to the current file by writing it like `\`${__dirname}/../Commands\``

Comment: The thing is the whole code looks like this: [edited question]

Comment: @mpen That would only work if the Commands folder existed in Reloaders; that's from just testing that theory.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If that code is in the `Reloaders` dir then `__dirname` is `C:/lib/Reloaders`, therefore `${__dirname}/..` goes up one dir, which is `C:/lib/` so the full thing should be `C:/lib/Commands` (or realistically `C:/lib/Reloaders/../Commands` but that's the same thing)

Comment: @mpen My apologises; I was wrong but now I have issue it doesn't actually delete it from the `cache` 
[New Edit]

Also can you put your comment as an Answer so I can accept it please.